Blender 4.2 Eevee displacement is spliting the mesh
Im testing Eevee displacement in 4.2 and it seams that eevee creates gaps on the mesh, like as splitting the mesh where there are uv seams. This is happening with image textures and also with procedural textures as noise. Suzanne is shaded smooth with 125k faces. Whats wrong? Thanks in advance :-)
Eevee displacement splits the mesh
